# prepareForSegue is not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i created three scenes, each of them has a button and a label as shown in image-1. Scene1 is linked to Scene2 through "Show Segue called scene1To2"
,Scene2 is linked to scene3 through "Show Segue called scene2To3" and finally Scene3 is linked to scene1 through "Show Segue called scene3To1".

I am trying to to call "prepareForSegue" when the button in scene1 is clicked, so I wrote the code shown in code1 section below..

but when i run the code the NSLog message "NSLog(@"transiting from scene1To2");" does not show up

please let me know why the NSLog message doesn't  show

**code1**:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a  
 //nib.
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
 // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)from1To2:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"Hi");

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"scene1To2" sender:self];
 }

 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
 {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"scene1To2"])
    {
        NSLog(@"transiting from scene1To2");
    }

  }

  @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method signature is wrong. See if this does the trick:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"scene1To2"])
    {
        NSLog(@"transiting from scene1To2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Segue links on the storyboard have you added the segue name to the segue identifier?

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this, you import the scene1To2 controller.

```
scene1To2 *view = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YOUR_STORYBOARD" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"scene1To2"];
[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
```

then you go to the other view controller